# How to add line numbers of files into Hive tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is there a way to load multiple files into a Hive table with the line number of the files? I can load each entry in a file fine and I know you can use input__file__name to get the name of the file of which the code came from so is there similarly a way to extract which line of the file the code is from?

Given these three arbitrary files:

```
a.txt           b.txt          c.txt
a1              b1             a3
b2              b2             b3
c3              c3             c4
```

is there a way to load them into a Hive table with the line numbers of the file of which it came from? Note: the actual files do not have number appended to them.
As a result, I want this outcome:

```
SELECT * FROM result;
```

Will yield:

```
Line_Number             code
1                       a1
1                       b1
1                       c1
2                       a2
2                       b2
2                       c2
3                       a3
3                       b3
3                       c3
```

Comment: Why a3 and b3 have line number 3? Where are c1 and a2 in files? Why there is no c4 in result?

Answer (score 0):

Using HiveQL only this is not possible because files are splittable and being read by many mappers. And splits are not lines. Files are broken into splits at byte, not line boundaries.  And splits are being processed independently by mappers. Mappers do know nothing about each other.
The simple way is to pre-process your files and add line number using shell/etc, then load them to the tables with line_number column defined. For example, using `awk`:

```
 awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",NR,$0}' a.txt > a1.txt
```

This will add a column with line number, tab separated. `a.txt` - is input file, `a1.txt` - result file

And if you want to use Map-reduce for this purpose, you need to implement your own `TextInputFormat`/`LineRecordReader` to return line number as a key instead byte offset. Also it should not split files to generate sequential numbers, and this will break parallelism. Maybe it's possible to do this employing custom counters to sync number generation between mappers. Anyway, to do this in fully distributed way is not so easy task. So, I suggest to pre-process files and add line numbers before loading to the table.

Comment: Hi @leftjoin thank you for your response, I will try this out and let you know how that works